# open whole folder in gedit

Tags: terminal, migration, gedit

Moving from OS X & Textmate to Ubuntu & gedit, the one feature of Textmate I am missing is it's command line tool.

With `mate` I was able to open a folder as a Textmate project using `mate .` from within the required directory. This is enormously useful as it speeds up my system navigation considerably.

Is there a way of doing the same or similar with gedit?

Comment: Did you check this yet `http://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins/FileBrowser`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered on Superuser, [Gedit open current directory from terminal - Ubuntu 10.10](https://superuser.com/questions/254823/gedit-open-current-directory-from-terminal-ubuntu-10-10). Looks like the answers are still relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't this as simple as

```
$ cd /directory/whose/files/you/need/to/open
$ gedit *
```

I just tried that with `geany` and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

As @kra3 said before you can open everything in one window with  `gedit *`.

But be careful as this opens everything in the folder, including non-text files and *folders* so I suggest  using a more specific glob pattern instead, such as `gedit *.cpp`(for all cpp files).

[More on glob patterns.](http://linux.die.net/man/7/glob)